# how to use dataclass in Python for complex __init__?

Tags: python

For instance, `self.env` has a complex implementation. How can I transfer it to use a dataclass?

```py
class Request(object):

    def __init__(self, env: str, email: str, password: str):
        self.env = env if len(env) > 2 else 'default'
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use @dataclass to init this class.

Comment: So like [this?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the `__post_init__(self)` method as described in the documentation.  This allows you to add validation steps after the init has occurred

```py
@dataclass
class Request:
    env: str
    email: str
    password: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.env = self.env if len(self.env)>2 else 'default'

Request('a', 'hello@world.com', 'qwerty1234')
# returns:
Request(env='default', email='hello@world.com', password='qwerty1234')

Request('test2', 'hello@world.com', 'qwerty1234')
# returns:
Request(env='test2', email='hello@world.com', password='qwerty1234')
```